# I have a script that makes a modal appear when a button is clicked. Is there a way to improve it so that the modal appears more quickly?

Tags: javascript

The modal contains the text "Added to Cart", and it appears after clicking any Add to Cart Button. I didn't write this script, and I know very little JS, but I was hoping to improve the speed of the modal appearance. It takes 2-6 seconds for the modal to appear after clicking the button, and I want to know if this is due to anything that I can control in this script. It appears to me that there isn't much for the script to load (the modal is just text and a container), so my guess is that the delay is being caused either by the animation settings or something else beyond what this script controls. Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track in this thinking?

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                        $(window).scroll(function(){
  var numPix = 200;
  var op = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop()) / numPix;
    if( op <= 0 ){
        $("#sticky").hide();
    } else {
        $("#sticky").show();
    }
    $("#sticky").css("opacity", op ); 
});
            $(".addToCart").removeClass("addToCartHide");
            $('.addToCart').click(function(){
                var skuUrl = "/transaction/addtocartbysku?sku=" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "&quantity=1";
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("POST", skuUrl, false);
                xhttp.send();
                $("#snackbar").animate( {"opacity": "1"}, 1000, "swing" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#snackbar").animate( {"opacity": "0"}, 1000, "swing" );
                }, 3000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Well you are using a synchronous call which is a bad practice and then showing it. So show the animation before the ajax call, not after.

Comment: @epascarello Forgive my lack of knowledge... this is a new concept to me. After looking into this, I agree that this seems like a bad design for this function. Can you point me to resources that would be helpful in figuring out how to change this to show the animation before the ajax call?

Comment: Move `$("#snackbar").animate( {"opacity": "1"}, 1000, "swing" );` before the ajax call. make the call asynchronous, not sure why you made it synchronous. `xhttp.open("POST", skuUrl, true);`

Comment: I didn't write the script. I have almost zero JS experience, and the concept of synchronous/asynchronous is new to me. But your changes worked, and I learned something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@epascarello found the correct answer. The modal was slow to appear because the animation was after a synchronous ajax call. Updated code to correct the order and make the ajax call asynchronous:

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                        $(window).scroll(function(){
  var numPix = 200;
  var op = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop()) / numPix;
    if( op <= 0 ){
        $("#sticky").hide();
    } else {
        $("#sticky").show();
    }
    $("#sticky").css("opacity", op ); 
});
            $(".addToCart").removeClass("addToCartHide");
            $('.addToCart').click(function(){
                var skuUrl = "/transaction/addtocartbysku?sku=" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "&quantity=1";
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                $("#snackbar").animate( {"opacity": "1"}, 1000, "swing" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#snackbar").animate( {"opacity": "0"}, 1000, "swing" );
                }, 3000);
                xhttp.open("POST", skuUrl, true);
                xhttp.send();
            });
        });
    </script>
```